# Execute Stored Procedure OnClick

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, onclick

How can I execute a stored procedure on `OnClick` button with no parameters? I have the following code behind:

```
Protected Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click

        Dim exec As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("up_ExportFile", conn)
        exec.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have already opened the connection just add the [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) method

```
Protected Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click

        Dim exec As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("up_ExportFile", conn)
        exec.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        exec.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Sub
```

However I suggest you to not keep a global variable holding your `SqlConnection` opened for the lifetime of your application. Remember that the ADO.NET provider for SqlServer implements the [connection pooling mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) and thus, opening a connection is a lightweight procedure.
So a better approach is

```
Using conn = new SqlConnection("your_connection_string_here")
    conn.Open()
    Dim exec As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("up_ExportFile", conn)
    exec.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    exec.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

In this way the connection object is created just when needed, and then closed and disposed 
[See Using Statememt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the advise. The missing exec.ExecuteNonQuery() did the trick. It is now executing. Answer accepted.